# Solving hyperbolic function using Newton-Raphson in python

Tags: python, math, decimal, hyperbolic-function, python-fractions

I was trying to solve an equation for the catenary and wanted to use the Newton-Raphson method.

[image]

```py
from math import sinh, cosh
y = 0.4                #Has taken to initiate the iteration.
k = 3/2
for _ in range(5):    #Iterations for Newton-Raphson Method
    y = y - (sinh(y)-y*k)/(cosh(y)-k)
    print(y)
print(y)
```

- **Output**

```py
-0.05174312094834577
9.262910138898434e-05
-5.298477449974456e-13
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

The unexpected output I was expecting `1/0.6164729394`

Comment: why isn't it `x + (sinh....`?

Comment: comments, make a good version history, that other users can track. What is the expected output?

Comment: Either the mathematical operation is incorrect or the number was so small it got a rounding error. https://pythonhosted.org/bigfloat/

Comment: What I mean is your output has 6 lines, what is the expected output that has 6 lines, I'm assuming the other values aren't matching up

Comment: I'm aware, but if you're debugging, why not start from the beginning. Is the first output (`-0.0517...`) correct?

Comment: Your solution is also "valid", in the sense that it leads to 0/0, which is pretty much undefined, and could therefore just as well be equal to 3/2. So your solution is not necessarily technically (w.r.t. the algorithm implementation) wrong, or perhaps not even mathematically wrong, but practically, you have to provide a good starting point for minimisation routines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curve has 3 roots:

[image: curve of sinh(y) - ky]

Your solution (y = 0) is one solution. There is a positive solution at 1.622, and a symmetrical negative one at -1.622.

If you don't know your formula, best is to actually view it (when possible; here it is easy to do), to gain some insight.

Further, Newton-Raphson's result, the root, will depend on your starting point, and how it converges towards a root (with big jumps or small jumps, depending on function and derivative value). Be aware of that.

---

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3472880/solving-sinh-x-kx